# ubuntu 100% CPU Load from apache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server

My Ubuntu server has a 100% CPU usage due to Apache. Actually there are only a few pages on the server that no one ever visits. What is the reason for this and how can I find out?

Thanks in Advance

[image]

vmstat 2

[image]

workers
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, your post does not show your Ubuntu has 100% CPU usage.

What it does show is a high load.  This means a lot of stuff waiting in the queue.  This could be caused by a lot of things, very often heavy disk IO, but there could be other things, like CPU bottlenecks and network IO. My guess is your web server is being heavily hit, and has not been tuned to handle the load.

I'd start with 2 things - running something like "sudo vmstat 2" to see how much CPU is in use, and also your memory, swap (which I doubt is a problem here) and bandwidth.

I'd also look at the Apache logs and see if something like a bot is hitting your site.

You can likely reduce the load by reducing the number of Apache workers (and doing other tuning things), but reducing the workers can cause outages for people trying to use Apache if it is under some kind of DoS or equivalent.

Comment: added the vmstat output

Comment: also added apache config.

Comment: Surprisingly your system does appear to be CPU bound.   You possibly need to work out why you have so many children, and google "Tune mpm_prefork" to get some saner values - but start by looking at the apache log file to see how much your server is being hit and by what, and maybe tackle that.